# SQL: MATCH AGAINST all elements in an array

Tags: sql, search, tags, match, against

I have an array of "tags" stored in a cookie. They are formatted as a series of words separated by `,`'s. I'm trying to return all rows in a table where every "tag" of that array is found in the "search_tags" column.

I currently have:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE MATCH search_tags AGAINST('". $_COOKIE['tags'] ."' IN BOOLEAN MODE);");
```

This almost works, but returns all the rows where ANY of the tags match. Instead of requiring ALL of the `$_COOKIE['tags']` to match the "search_tags" column.

An alternative solution could be where it stays as an OR query but instead sorts the results by number of matches or relevance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `+` operator in [boolean mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html) to assert that a word must be present, so if you convert the tags from a comma separated list to a `+` separated list that should give you the result you want:

```
$tags = '+' . implode(' +', explode(',', $_COOKIE['tags']));
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE MATCH search_tags AGAINST('$tags' IN BOOLEAN MODE);");
```

Note if you might have spaces after the commas, you should use `preg_split('/,\s*/', $_COOKIE['tags'])` instead of the `explode`.